# How do i update DBContext & pocos after DB schema change?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've always used the edmx file approach and just run "update from database".  Now i am using Code first from existing database.

When the DBA changes the database schema, how do I update my dbcontext file and POCOs to match? Is that what migrations are for? Do I just delete everything int he models folder and re-create?

Comment: Personally I just create the classes manually, and edit existing ones if required. It's called 'code-first' because normally you'd make the code changes first, then update the DB accordingly.

Comment: Makes sense.  I guess I am just used to the db first way.

Comment: So should i not do code first if I dont have control of the db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Code-First" has two different meanings in EF.  It's both a Modeling workflow and a Mapping style.  You can do Code-First Mapping with Database-First Modeling.  You simply regenerate your entity types after changing the database, or change them manually to match the database change.  This is what's called "Code-First From and Existing Database"

Comment: "You simply regenerate your entity types after changing the database" 

How do I do this part? 
1. Delete the dbcontext file, the auto-generated pocos then 
2. Right click > add ado entity thingy >code first from existing, etc etc?

Comment: Yep.  Or do that into a separate project and then move them to your main project.

Comment: Cool, thanks.  Is it a bad idea to do code first if I dont have control of the DB?  I am not allowed to make schema changes.  I switched to code first because the edmx file always seemed so big and code first just seems "lighter". That is the only reason I switched.

Comment: Code first to an existing database is my favorite way to use EF.  You're spot-on about the "lightness", and it's the only way to do Database-First Modeling in EF Core.  Customizing the mapping between your objects and database is just so much easier with attributes/fluent/etc.  And EDMX mapping complicated and IMO not worth learning.